# R: Retrieving multiple variable of a nested list

Tags: r, list

I am looking at vote data and it's a nested list. I am trying to get multiple variable on each element of my list (example bellow )

So for each element "vote" i am trying to get the uid and the list of individual that vote for or against ("pours" and "contre" ) the law.

I try to simplify the original data ( can be found [here](http://data.assemblee-nationale.fr/static/openData/repository/LOI/scrutins/Scrutins_XIV.json.zip) )

```
This is the simplified list i came up with :
scrutin1_detail<-list(uid="VTANR5L14V1",organref="P0644420")
scrutin1_vote1_for<-list(acteurref="PA1816",mandatRef="PM645051")
scrutin1_vote2_for<-list(acteurref="PA1817",mandatRef="PM645052")
scrutin1_vote3_for<-list(acteurref="PA1818",mandatRef="PM645053")
scrutin1_vote_for<-list(scrutin1_vote1_for,scrutin1_vote2_for,scrutin1_vote3_for)

scrutin1_vote1_against<-list(acteurref="PA1816",mandatRef="PM645051")
scrutin1_vote2_against<-list(acteurref="PA1817",mandatRef="PM645052")
scrutin1_vote3_against<-list(acteurref="PA1818",mandatRef="PM645053")
scrutin1_vote_against<-list(scrutin1_vote1_against,scrutin1_vote2_against,scrutin1_vote3_against)

votant1<-list(pours=scrutin1_vote_for,contres=scrutin1_vote_against)
vote1<-list(decompte_nominatif=votant1)
ventilationVotes1<-list(vote=vote1)
scrutin1<-list(scrutin1_detail,list(ventilationVotes=ventilationVotes1))


# Scrutin 2

scrutin2_detail<-list(uid="VTANR5L14V5",organref="P0644423")
scrutin2_vote1_for<-list(acteurref="PA1816",mandatRef="PM645051")
scrutin2_vote2_for<-list(acteurref="PA1817",mandatRef="PM645052")
scrutin2_vote3_for<-list(acteurref="PA1818",mandatRef="PM645053")
scrutin2_vote_for<-list(scrutin1_vote1_for,scrutin1_vote2_for,scrutin1_vote3_for)

scrutin2_vote1_against<-list(acteurref="PA1816",mandatRef="PM645051")
scrutin2_vote2_against<-list(acteurref="PA1817",mandatRef="PM645052")
scrutin2_vote3_against<-list(acteurref="PA1818",mandatRef="PM645053")
scrutin2_vote_against<-list(scrutin2_vote1_against,scrutin2_vote2_against,scrutin2_vote3_against)

scrutin2_votant1<-list(pours=scrutin2_vote_for,contres=scrutin2_vote_against)
scrutin2_vote1<-list(decompte_nominatif=scrutin2_votant1)
scrutin2_ventilationVotes1<-list(vote=scrutin2_vote1)
scrutin2<-list(scrutin2_detail,list(ventilationVotes=scrutin2_ventilationVotes1))
scrutins<-list(scrutins=list(scrutin=list(scrutin1,scrutin2)))
```

So i am looking at the end ( but i am really interested to understand how to do it as i run into this problem quite often ) to build a dataframe with these column :

- uid
- For/against (if it was in the list "pour"(for) or "contre" (against)
  -acteurref
  -mandatref

Comment: Did you try reading in the data with `jsonlite::fromJSON()`? It's still huge, but at least it's nested data.frames that you can subset with `$`.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I don't speak (or read French) and so am not able to make many correct guesses as to the meaning of names of items in the object constructed using alistaire's suggestion:

```
library(jsonlite)
scrutin1_detail <- fromJSON("~/Downloads/Scrutins_XIV.json")

> length(scrutin1_detail[[1]])
[1] 1
> length(scrutin1_detail[[1]][[1]])
[1] 18
> names(scrutin1_detail[[1]][[1]])

 [1] "@xmlns:xsi"              "uid"                    
 [3] "numero"                  "organeRef"              
 [5] "legislature"             "sessionRef"             
 [7] "seanceRef"               "dateScrutin"            
 [9] "quantiemeJourSeance"     "typeVote"               
[11] "sort"                    "titre"                  
[13] "demandeur"               "objet"                  
[15] "modePublicationDesVotes" "syntheseVote"           
[17] "ventilationVotes"        "miseAuPoint"            
> str(scrutin1_detail[[1]][[1]]$uid)
 chr [1:1219] "VTANR5L14V1" "VTANR5L14V2" "VTANR5L14V3" ...

> table( scrutin1_detail[[1]][[1]]$organeRef)

PO644420 
    1219 
> table( scrutin1_detail[[1]][[1]]$sessionRef)

SCR5A2012E1 SCR5A2012E2 SCR5A2013E1 SCR5A2013E3 SCR5A2013O1 SCR5A2014E1 
         15           5          42           4         529          50 
SCR5A2014E2 SCR5A2014O1 SCR5A2015E1 SCR5A2015E2 SCR5A2015O1 SCR5A2016O1 
          7         253          18           5         236          55
```

Maybe you should help us Anglophones to make sense of this. It is very beneficial to provide context rather than just code.

Comment: Hi,thanks for all your answer, yes use fromJson to load the data like that
download.file("http://data.assemblee-nationale.fr/static/openData/repository/LOI/scrutins/Scrutins_XIV.json.zip",destfile = "data/Scrutins_XIV.json.zip",method='curl')
con<-unz("data/Scrutins_XIV.json.zip",filename="Scrutins_XIV.json")
library("rjson")
json_file <-"./data/Scrutins_XIV.json"
json_data <- fromJSON(paste(readLines(json_file), collapse=""))

Comment: We had a big vote in france for a change in constitution but only 25 % of the chamber vote.So i interested to see who come and vote the law,who never show up,as also what they vote.

Comment: A scrutin is a vote inside each scrutin there is a group "ventilationVotes" meaning the split of vote,which group vote for or against the law.Inside this list there is group call "groupe",its a political group and inside each "groupe" there is a group "decompteNominative" meaning vote per individual ( which is what i am interested in ). Inside this group there is three group,first is "NonVotants" is the list of person that didn't show up.

Comment: Then a there is group "pours" meaning the list of person voting for the law and finally a group call "contres" which mean the list of individual that vote against the law.
Hope it help